# Admin View Normal Users Account Membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I'm using Membeship provider,Is there any technique that Admin role view other Normal User roles accounts ?

Simply,When admin logged in and then he needs to view Other Users UserPage(page that goes after loggedIn )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary assign admin role to that user when access that account from inside the admin panel.